# Function that returns $0$ for all negative values

Tags: functions

I need a function that returns $0$ if the given number is negative, and otherwise doesn't change the number.

Example:
$$y(-5)=0,\ y(-2)=0,\ y(0)=0,\ y(3)=3,\ y(2566)=2566.$$

Does such a function exist?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can take for example
$$\frac{|x|+x}{2}.$$
You can construct similar examples.

Comment: Like what else?

Answer (score 10):

Just use

$$f(x) = \max\{x,0\}$$

This way it's clear what your function do

Answer (score 3):

Exotic: $0^{\sqrt{x^2}-x}\cdot x$.

Comment: It is undefined at 1

Comment: Not if we agree upon $0^0=1$.

Comment: Well that's a kind of cheating